# Years not showing in form_dropdown option value Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this function

```
public function year() {
    $years = array_merge_recursive(
        array('' => 'Please Select'),
        array_combine(range(date("Y"), 1945), range(date("Y"), 1945))
    );

    return $years;      
}
```

And on my controller I send to view like

```
$this->data['byear'] = $this->birthday->year(); 

if ($this->input->post('bd3')) {
    $this->data['bd3'] = $this->input->post('bd3');
} else {
    $this->data['bd3'] = '';
}

$this->data['children'] = array(
    'common/header',
    'common/footer',
    'common/navbar' 
);

$this->load->render('account/register', $this->data);
```

And then on the view

```
<?php echo form_dropdown('bd3', $byear, $bd3, array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'birthday'));?>
```

How ever the **option value** on view displays numbers from 1 to 72 which is wrong.

> Question How can I make sure the **option value** displays the **YEARS**?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change **array_merge_recursive** to **array_replace_recursive**

```
public function year() {
    $years = array_replace_recursive(
        array('' => 'Please Select'),
        array_combine(range(date("Y"), 1945), range(date("Y"), 1945))
    );

    return $years;      
}
```

Or just add them together.

```
public function year() {
        $years = array('' => 'Please Select') + array_combine(range(date("Y"), 1945), range(date("Y"), 1945));
        return $years;
    }
```